# Winrt ListView Scroll To any Item via code?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am trying to scroll to particular item in a ListView.
The ListView Contains 500 items ("Questions"). I want to navigate it to particular question number.

ListView in xaml

```
<ListView x:Name="LstQuestions" SelectionMode="None" Grid.Row="1" d:IsLocked="True">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"/>
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

ListView items are loaded from code.

```
InitializeComponent();
for(int i=1;i<= 500; i++)
{
     Button btn = new Button();
     btn.Width = 120;
     btn.Height = 120;
     btn.Click += Btn_Click;
     btn.Content = i;
     LstQuestions.Items.Add(btn);
}
LstQuestions.UpdateLayout();

LstQuestions.ScrollIntoView((Button)LstQuestions.Items[_CurrentQuestionNumber]);
```

What I am trying is I have a setting that stores the current question number and I want it to automatically scroll it to that question number in ListView.

I tried ListView.ScrollIntoView and ListView.MakeVisible methods. Nothing worked.

I also found one more thing. The above code works fine in MainPage. However if I navigated 
`Frame.Navigate(typeof(Questions))` 
then the above code wont work in Questions page.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Do you call ScrollIntoView directly after adding them?

Comment: Yes  After the for loop. For loop will be called after initializing the component.

Comment: Okay then try to call LstQuestion.UpdateLayout() before ScrollIntoView

Comment: I tried that didn't work.

Comment: This did the trick for me..

Comment: It will work in wpf. However it is not working in windows apps. Here is what I do. The program loads the settings. Then user selects the subject. Questions based on that subjects will be loaded. Till now it works fine however it won't scroll.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102723/discussion-between-ajit-hegde-and-thetanic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the problem was. But I found out that if you call ScrollIntoView from an event it will work.

So I created Layout_Updated event. Called the ScrollIntoView from that event.

```
<ListView x:Name="LstQuestions" SelectionMode="None" Grid.Row="1" LayoutUpdated="LstQuestions_LayoutUpdated" d:IsLocked="True">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"/>
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>

public Questions()
{  
    InitializeComponent();
    for(int i=1;i<= 500; i++)
    {
         Button btn = new Button();
         btn.Width = 120;
         btn.Height = 120;
         btn.Click += Btn_Click;
         btn.Content = i;
         LstQuestions.Items.Add(btn);
    }
    LstQuestions.UpdateLayout();
}
private void LstQuestions_LayoutUpdated(object sender, object e)
{
   LstQuestions.ScrollIntoView(LstQuestions.Items[_CurrentQuestionNumber]);
}
```

Now it works.